# Type error when using Moq to mock dependency for object being tested

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I have a validation class I am trying to test `FluentQuestionAnswerValidator`, but this class has a dependency `IQuestionAnswerRepository` which must be passed through the constructor in order to instantiate the validator class.

In order to try and instantiate the class I am using Moq to mock the repository which can then be passed through to the validator.

However I am getting a type error when I attempt to pass in the mocked repository into the validator when instantiating it:

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 
'Moq.Mock<IQuestionAnswerRepository>' to 'IQuestionAnswerRepository'
```

How do I change the code I've got so that it will accept the mocked repository as its dependency?

```
class QuestionAnswerValidationTest
    {
        private QuestionAnswer _qaTest;
        private FluentQuestionAnswerValidator _validator;
        private Mock<IQuestionAnswerRepository> mockRepo;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _qaTest = new QuestionAnswer()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Type = "Number",
                Required = true,
                QuestionSection = 1,
            };

            QuestionAnswer qa = new QuestionAnswer()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Type = "String",
                Required = true,
                QuestionSection = 1,
                Answer = "Yes",
                ConditionalQuestionId = null,
                ConditionalQuestionAnswered = null
            };

            Dictionary<int, QuestionAnswer> questionMap = new Dictionary<int, QuestionAnswer>();
            questionMap.Add(qa.Id, qa);

            mockRepo = new Mock<IQuestionAnswerRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            mockRepo.Setup(p => p.QuestionMap).Returns(questionMap);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Validate_AnswerDoesNotMatchQuestionType_ProducesValidationError()
        {
            _qaTest.Answer = "string";

            _validator = new FluentQuestionAnswerValidator(_qaTest, mockRepo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I´m pretty sure you don´t need to provide the *mock*, but *the mocked object*, which is `mockRepo.object`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FluentQuestionAnswerValidator` obviously expects an instance of `IQuestionAnswerRepository`, not `Mock<IQuestionAnswerRepository>`. As there is no implicit conversion between those two you get the error.

What you want to provide actually is therefor not the mock itself, but the **instance** being created by the framework. So use this instead:

```
_validator = new FluentQuestionAnswerValidator(_qaTest, mockRepo.Object);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Will using `mockRepo.Object` still give me the same versatility?

Comment: @user9754798 I´m not sure what you mean by this. The mock doesn´t give you *any* versatility, because it just does not compile. The framework creates some object for you which implements your interface in the way you determine by using `Setup`. So `mockRepo.Object` contains the behaviour you set up before.